# WCF and embedded systems

Tags: wcf, web-services, embedded

I am working on a project that involves an embedded system which runs a non-microsoft OS with a C program for the application and am developing .NET software for its end user applications.  For remote configuring with the .NET software (which can go across firewalls), I am considering using WCF.  I know only a little about WCF so far but I've read that it is supposed to be interoperable with environments other than .NET.  The embedded environment has an HTTP stack but no built in support for web services.  Does anyone have any experience with this kind of thing or know if it would be appropriate at all? If so please provide some advice or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add more information about what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF is interoperable because it's accessed over HTTP. Visual Studio can help you build client libraries very quickly for WCF, but client access to WCF doesn't require anything other than HTTP calls with the proper payload.  If you're looking at a remote server call and your built-in support in your embedded environment is basic HTTP, look at building your server-side as REST-formatted methods.  Your debugger will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What kinds of data are you planning on transferring back and forth? For something this low level and proprietary I would recommend sticking with good old fashioned Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I will be passing configuration data back and forth...basically to enable technical support staff to remotely program the device.  If I were using sockets this could be binary data, but there is a requirement that customers with firewalls shouldn't need to open any ports.  Because of this I was thinking of sending XML over HTTP.  So, is it better to use WCF or REST on the server side? Or WCF with REST?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about your "customers with firewalls" requirement. Sockets with binary data or XML over HTTP can use any port (not just port 80), and I'm curious if your device will be "listening" on the network, or just making an outbound connection. If your device is listening, you will need to open a port on the firewall. Making an outbound connection ("phoning home") is much easier on the firewall.

So I think you could use sockets and binary data. However, I have faced similar issues on the last two projects, and I really wanted to implement WCF using REST on the embedded device, but no one else wanted to do it - I'm hoping someone else will be first, and publish some results!

Good Luck! (and post your results!)